# Hangfire single instance recurring job

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

I am trying to use Hangfire to run a recurring job in the background that polls data from another website, the issue is that I don't want the recurring job to run if the previous job is still running.

I've read through the documentation but can't seem to find the answer. Is there a way to have a recurring job that runs every 10 minutes but skips if the previous task is not done yet?

```cs
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.MapSignalR();

    // Hangfire
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
        .UseSqlServerStorage("DatabaseContext");

    app.UseHangfireDashboard();
    app.UseHangfireServer();

    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("site-parser", () => SiteParserService.RunAll(), Cron.Minutely, TimeZoneInfo.Utc);

    ConfigureAuth(app);
}
```

Comment: Here is a suggestion: Simply queue the job as a single instance. Then, if the job completes successfully, you execute a final step in the job. The final step of your job will queue the job to execute again in 10 minutes. Won't that provide you the functionality you need?

Comment: Do you mean the last execution of the same recurring task?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use;
`[DisableConcurrentExecution(10 * 60)]` attribute on the job method.

Here you can find information about this attribute:
http://odinserj.net/2014/05/21/hangfire-0.8.2-released/

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public delegate void LockWrapperDelegateVoid();

    /* Job Locker. One job can work at current moment. Different jobs can work parallel */
    public static class JobLocker
    {
        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool> _locks = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool>();

        private static string LocksTryAdd(string lockerName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lockerName))  // lock by procedure's name (in this example = "JobProcedure")
            {
                lockerName = new StackFrame(2).GetMethod().Name;
            }
            if (!_locks.ContainsKey(lockerName))
            {
                _locks.TryAdd(lockerName, false);
            }
            return lockerName;
        }

        public static void LockWrapperVoid(string lockerName, LockWrapperDelegateVoid lockWrapperDelegateVoid)
        {
            lockerName = LocksTryAdd(lockerName);
            if (!_locks[lockerName])
            {
                _locks[lockerName] = true;
                try
                {
                    lockWrapperDelegateVoid();
                }
                finally
                {
                    _locks[lockerName] = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// USING

// JOB description
TryAddOrUpdateJob("JOB TITLE", () => JobManager.JobProcedure(), "* * * * *", TimeZoneInfo.Utc, "queueDefault");  // every one minute


public static void JobProcedure()
{
    // very important. You can use "BlockArea" instead null and use one area if several jobs depend each other
    // if null - area will have name like as the procedure ("JobProcedure")
    JobLocker.LockWrapperVoid(null, () =>  
    {
        //your code here
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2 * 1000 * 60); // timeout - 2 minutes
    });
}
```